# connecting to mysql using jdbc from node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, jdbc

I am connecting to JDBC using npm module JDBC from node.js

I am successfully connected to the database I pulled the data, I have all decimal,big int, and varchar in MySQL but this JDBC result set is giving 
nodeJava_java_math_BigDecimal {} for the decimal columns.

How to get my complete values?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question, this seems like to little information to answer the question.  For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You may want to find if there is node.js specific driver for MySQL instead of jumping through hoops of using Java through Node.js to connect to MySQL. In any case `java.math.BigDecimal` is the right type for decimal columns in JDBC. Consider checking the documentation of the node.js module you're using to see if they give any indication of how to handle those java types from node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `JSON.parse()` for `nodeJava_java_math_BigDecimal {}` values.

**For Example:** I was trying to get database tables and row numbers for each, so; i used this query:

```
SELECT table_name as tName, num_rows as rNumber FROM user_tables
```

then i had list of objects with tName and rNumber properties, but rNumber type is nodeJava_java_math_BigDecimal{}, just i had to get value like this:

```
let rowNumber = JSON.parse(tables[0].rNumber);
```